# Go Gorilla Mux "match anything" path template

Tags: go, gorilla

What is the proper syntax to create a simple "match anything" handler?

`mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true).Path("/")....`

The above code seems to strictly match `/` and `/foo` won't get matched

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
router := mux.NewRouter().PathPrefix("/")
```

Comment: as per the docs, StrictSlash() has no effect when used with PathPrefix()

Answer (score 11):

You can use `mux.Route.HandlerFunc` together with `mux.Router.PathPrefix`:

```golang
r := mux.NewRouter()

// route catalog to catalogHandler:
r.HandleFunc("/catalog/{id}", catalogHandler) 

// route everything else to defaultHandler:
r.PathPrefix("/").HandlerFunc(defaultHandler)
```

Note the difference in names (`HandlerFunc` vs `HandleFunc`).